# Is it possible to set the startup form to be a static string value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, startup, static-members

As we know we can specify which view to start up by setting the property `StartupUri` as the below code.

```
<Application x:Class="SomeClass"
             xmlns  ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             >
</Application>
```

My question: Can we put in a static string value for the view name, ie. `MainWindow.xaml`?

I tried below code but it doesn't work. Please share if you know how to. Thank you!

```
<Application x:Class="Demo.WPFSkill.App"
             xmlns  ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyPublicStaticClassNamespace"

             StartupUri="{x:Static Member=local:MyPublicStaticClass.AStaticValue}"
             >
</Application>
```

**Edit**
My purpose: To put in the right name to start the application in such a way that NOT rely on a string value.

Thanks to `mzabsky`, I think I better code it in the code behind as below code.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the StartupUri parameter from XAML and open the window manually from the App class from C# code.

EDIT:

Example (assuming the static value is a type name of the main window class):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
         Window window = (Window) Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType(MyPublicStaticClass.AStaticValue));
         window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be lovely and accepted if you can post a guideline on how to do that given the static value.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion helps me a lot. Chosen yours as accepted.

Comment: Happy to help. I added example on how to create a window if you know only its type name string.